# Token provider config for two Identity users

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity

I have two  `AddIdentityCore` for my application users and I want to generate token for reset password.

```
services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationCompany>().AddRoles<CompanyRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CompanyDbContext>().AddTokenProvider<MyCustomTokenProvider<ApplicationCompany>>("EDefault");


services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationEmployee>().AddRoles<EmployeeRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EmployeeDbContext>().AddTokenProvider<MyCustomTokenProvider<ApplicationEmployee>>("EDefault");
```

I'm getting error in `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync`:

> Error: no iusertwofactortokenprovider named 'default' is registered.

```
private async Task<(string giud, string firstName)> CreateResetPasswordData(ApplicationCompany user)
{
        try
        {
            var token = await _companyManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Reset password token generated");
            return (token, user.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex, "Failed to create reset password token");
            throw;
        }
}
```

I tried creating a custom token provider but it did not work as shown in the docs, but it does not work.

Please help me and do mention important thinks if missing